# Monitoring TikTok hashtags and their changes in daily ranking

Tags: tiktok, webtrends

I am a **Data Strategist** and spend my life trying to understand **TikTok trends**. I spend a lot of time on the app and I want to reduce that time and use my time more effectively. I spend a lot of time on this site - https://ads.tiktok.com/business/creativecenter/inspiration/popular/hashtag/pad/en

The site gives a list of hashtags used in TikTok videos and ranks them.

I **want to monitor the movements in these trends**, which means the info would have to be collected frequently (min. daily) and once a week/fortnightly/monthly (whatever is most appropriate) put together a report of trends and which trends to watch out for etc.

Does anyone have recommendations on how to approach this? **Any guidance/advice at all would be greatly appreciated!**

Thanks in advance